# Does there exist a $k$-chromatic graph $G$ in which no color class of a $k$-coloring of $G$ contain at least $\alpha (G)-2$ vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

Does there exist a $k$-chromatic graph $G$ in which no color class of a $k$-coloring of $G$ contain at least $\alpha (G)-2$ vertices?

My gut telling me that the answer should be no. So I tried to find a contradiction.

Here is what I got so far.

Since $G$ is $k-chromatic$, $\chi(G)=k$. Let $V_1, V_2,\ldots, V_k$ be the color classes of $G$. Since no color class of a $k-coloring$ of $G$ contain at least $\alpha (G)-2$ vertices, we have

$$|V_i|<\alpha(G)-2$$

now if I multiply both side by $k$, then I got

$$|V_i|k=n<k(\alpha(G)-2) $$

There is a theorem that say

$$\frac{n}{\alpha(G)} \leq \chi(G) \leq n-\alpha(G)+1$$

Substitute in some value and I got

$$\frac{k(\alpha(G)-2)}{\alpha(G)} < k < k(\alpha(G)-2)-\alpha(G)+1$$

I tried to find a contradiction from the above inequality, but got no luck. I wonder if anyone would give me a hint please.

Comment: $\alpha(G)$ is the maximum number of independent vertices.

Comment: I changed $k-chromatic$ to $k$-chromatic.  There is a reason why your hyphen came out looking like a minus sign instead of a hyphen. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for $k \geq 3$, the following construction results in $k$-chromatic graph whose color classes have at most $\alpha - 3$ vertices.

Consider a $k$-multipartite graph with $p$ vertices in each partition. To one of the vertex join $p(k-1)$ isolated vertices by edges. So $\alpha = p + p(k-1) = pk$. Now give the following coloring. Distribute the $p(k-1)$ vertices into the other $k-1$ partitions i.e. $p$ per partition. Assign a different color to each partition. So we have a proper $k$-coloring, and maximum size of a color class is $2p$ which is at most $\alpha-3$ i.e. $pk-3$ for $k\geq 3$ and a sufficiently large $p$ ($p>6 $ will do).

For $k=2$, see bof's comment below which gives an example i.e. joining centers of two copies of $K_{1,100}$.

Comment: so you have $k$ component, each of them have $p$ vertices, and you connect each of $p(k-1)$ vertices from each component to $k-1$ remaining components?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif There are $k$ components, each having $p$ vertices. And I add further $p(k-1)$ vertices and join them to any vertex of the previous complete multi partite graph. So in total there are $np+p(k-1)$ vertices. $\alpha = p+p(k-1) = pk$, and the maximum size of the color class defined in the above answer is $p+p=2p$, which satisfies your conditions under some restrictions (given above).

Comment: @bof yup sorry for the mistake.

Comment: In the question, does "no color class of a $k$-coloring of $G$ contains at least $\alpha$ vertices" mean "for every $k$-coloring of $G$, no color class contains at least $\alpha$ vertices", or does it mean "there exists a $k$-coloring of $G$ such that no color class contains at least $\alpha$ vertices"? In your example, you chose a coloring where the maximum size of a color class is $2p$, but there is also a proper coloring where the maximum size of a color class is $pk$. (With my construction the question doesn't arise, as the graph is **uniquely** $k$-colorable.)

Comment: @bof I just gave an instance to show as a counter example. I did not think in terms of uniqueness.

Comment: @Umakant: What I meant was, it is not clear (to me) from the wording whether the OP intended the **stronger** assertion "for **every** $k$-coloring of $G$, no color class contains $\alpha$ vertices" or the **weaker** assertion "there exists **some** $k$-coloring of $G$ such that no color class contains $\alpha$ vertices. It seems to me that your construction only answers the weaker interpretation. In my example, the strong and weak interpretations are equivalent, because the graph admits only one proper $k$-coloring.

Comment: @bof ya its fine, I also was a bit confused but I got the answer to the weaker notion and you addressed the stronger notion. Both grounds covered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample with $k=2$. Let $G$ be the tree with degree sequence $5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.$ Then $\alpha(G)=8$, the unique independent set of size $8$ consisting of the eight vertices of degree one. Of course $\chi(G)=2$, and the unique proper $2$-coloring of $G$ has color classes of size $5$.

More generally, given integers $k,n\ge2$, we can construct a uniquely $k$-colorable graph $G$ such that each of the $k$ color classes has size $n$ and $\alpha(G)=k(n-1)$. Namely, let $V(G)=V=V_1\cup V_2\cup\cdots\cup V_k$ where $V_1,V_2,\dots,V_k$ are pairwise disjoint $n$-element sets; choose vertices $v_1\in V_1,v_2\in V_2,\dots,v_k\in V_k$, and let $E(G)=\bigcup_{i=1}^k\{v_iw:w\in V\setminus V_i\}$. The example in the preceding paragraph is the case $k=2,n=5$.